# how to set a long value in java to 2^64-1?

Tags: java

Java doesn't have support for unsigned integers but if you treat the `long`s as unsigned, you can do multiplications just fine.

But what is the best way to set a `long` from `2^63+1` to `2^64-1`?

`Long.MAX_VALUE` is `0x7fffffffffffffffL`;

The only way I know is

`long maximumUnsigned = new BigInteger("18446744073709551615").longValue()` (where is `18446744073709551615 = 2^64-1`)

Doing `long maximumUnsigned = -1` would work also but I find this problematic and could trick the readers into thinking it's negative.

Comment: "Doing long maximumUnsigned = -1 would work also but I find this problematic and could trick the readers into thinking it's negative" - it *is* negative. You may decide to *use* it as if it were an unsigned type, but the value of the variable is definitely negative. Fundamentally, you *can't* set a `long` to a value above 2^63-1. If you decide to effectively ignore the intended use of a data type (in this case as a signed integer) you should *expect* that to end up looking a bit odd in source code.

Comment: Long.MAX_VALUE is

Comment: @JonSkeet actually java has explicit support for unsigned longs, just not in the type. That's what the Long.toUnsignedString or Long.compareUnsigned exist, so it's not actually negative, you decide

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: No, it *is* negative - there are just helper methods for "treat this in an unusual way". The value is very definitely negative. The variable is of type `long`, and that's a signed integer type. The existence of helper methods doesn't change the nature of the type itself. (I could write a helper method that printed `byte` values as if they were the top 8 bits of a 64-bit value - that wouldn't mean that `byte` suddenly has a larger range.)

Comment: Why do you want this? Why can't you just use `BigInteger`?

Comment: I would just use `-1L`, but there are lots of ways to make it look big, like `(2L<<63)-1`, `Long.MAX_VALUE*2+1`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn’t seem to be a perfect solution. Since, as you say, `Long.MAX_VALUE` is `0x7fffffffffffffffL`, I think I’d just put an `F` in the first position too:

```
    long maxUnsignedLong = 0xFFFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFFL;
    System.out.println(Long.toUnsignedString(maxUnsignedLong));
```

Output:

> 18446744073709551615

Advantages:

1. For readers who know that a `long` is 64 bits and are comfortable with hexadecimal numbers it’s easier to read than 18446744073709551615.
2. It doesn’t give the reader the impression that the number should be understood as a negative number (no matter that Jon Skeet is of course correct that it *is* negative).

Comment: How is this better than `long maxUnsignedLong = -1;`? https://java.godbolt.org/z/YadY9nz98

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Thanks for the question. Whether it’s better depends entirely on style, taste and opinion. See my edit for what I think.